# parsing xml in R that has one node

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I have an XML file with following data.

I am only interested in extracting node of xaxiscategories and integer data under name node where name has word 'House'

I tried doing      xmlRoot but it appears its is all one node.

I tried          xmlTreeParse     (data, asText = TRUE) , I get error 
cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'

My question is how to i penetrate the xml that is encapsulated in 1 node

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <soap:Body>
     <GetMedianSalePriceJsonResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <GetMedianSalePriceJsonResult>
         <xAxisCategories>
           <string>2013 - Q3</string>
            <string>2013 - Q4</string>
              </xAxisCategories>
               <series>
                 <Series>
                 <name>House - Abbotsford</name>
                 <data>
                 <int>950000</int>
                 <int>753500</int>
                  </data>
                     </Series>
                 <Series>
                 <name>Unit - Apollo Bay</name>
                     <data>
                    <int>150000</int>
                    <int>853500</int>
                   </data>
                         </Series>
                       </series>
                      </GetMedianSalePriceJsonResult>
                      </GetMedianSalePriceJsonResponse>
                       </soap:Body>
                 </soap:Envelope>
```

I want to have 
[image]

Comment: This XML is malformed. There is no closing `</data>` tag.

Comment: my bad in copying.

Comment: I realize you're also trying to sanitize the data (which is fine) but you're still missing tags/have malformed tags. Perhaps run your content through https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html before re-editing/posting.